# Inserting a Rails [each..do] loop inside the jQuery append method

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, loops, append

Is there a way to insert a Rails loop within the jQuery append method without using a partial?  Here's the code that I'm trying to implement:

```
$('#selector').append('<%=j @stuff.each do |item| %>test<%=j end %>');
```

I know that I can put the rails loop into a partial and call the partial in the append method - that code will work (I've tested it).  But for the purposes of my application, I'd prefer to not call a partial in the append method.

Comment: what do you need to append? an array, text? what is `test`?

Comment: I'm trying to append a rails loop (an ".each" "do" loop).  "Test" is just to let me know how many times the loop iterates.  You can remove text and see that the code in my question results in an error.  on the other hand, if I stuff all that in a partial and then call the partial with the append method, everything works.

Comment: what should the processed js look like?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's my understanding that `js.erb` only works in the `views` folder (not the `asset pipeline`). This means you can't call this kind of erb code in the asset pipeline

If you're loading the js outside of the asset pipeline, why don't you try this:

```
#app/views/controller/your_js.js.erb
<% @stuff.each do |item| %>
    $('#selector').append('<%=j item %>');
<% end %>
```

Comment: Thanks a bunch, Rich!  Your solution worked like a charm.  I didn't know that js.erb was processed by the asset pipeline (looks like I should probably try to understand how the pipeline works in Rails 4).  I thought it was just a syntactical issue that I was dealing with but looks like that wasn't the case.  Thanks again!

Comment: No problem, glad it helped! I've been stung by the same issue before